# VBA Copy and Paste based on title matching

Tags: excel, vba, lookup, matching

I have written this code to copy values from Worksheet1 to Worksheet2 based on matching ID numbers. I want to make it more efficient by also being able to recognise in what column the data needs to be pasted without using the Offset(,3) to paste the values 3 columns away from the original ID number. I am using the offset in both of my worksheets.

I currently have this,

```
Set lkp = ws_Worksheet2.Range(ws_Worksheet2.Cells(6, 2), ws_Worksheet2.Cells(1235, 2).End(xlUp))
Set rng1 = ws_Worksheet1.Range(ws_Worksheet1.Cells(2, 1), ws_Worksheet1.Cells(1235, 1).End(xlUp))

For Each cll In lkp.Rows

    On Error Resume Next
    
    temp_var = cll.Value
    Set fnd = rng1.Find(What:=cll.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
    
        cll.Offset(, 10).Value = fnd.Offset(, 1).Value
        cll.Offset(, 18).Value = fnd.Offset(, 2).Value
        cll.Offset(, 21).Value = fnd.Offset(, 9).Value
        cll.Offset(, 24).Value = fnd.Offset(, 3).Value
        cll.Offset(, 25).Value = fnd.Offset(, 4).Value
        cll.Offset(, 28).Value = fnd.Offset(, 8).Value 
        
    End If
Next cll
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd per se think the .Offset is being inefficient but were you looking for something like `Cells(cll.Row,12).Value = ws_Worksheet1.Cells(fnd.Row,2).Value` ?

Comment: Why should it be more efficient in the way you suggest trying? Then, I asked you on a comment to your related previous question: Why using `On Error Resume  next` in this context? It does not help at all, just  not let VBA raising an error to make you seeing which mistake you did...

Comment: I have now deleted On Error Resume next. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is inefficient because if the columns were to change, then you'll have to go back to the code and change the offset which is a pain. It is easier to paste the values knowing that both worksheets have the same title name

Comment: It is perfectly viable to do that but you'll have to set these variables then in front of the for loop something along the lines of `colSh1FirstName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("First Name", ws_Worksheet2.Rows(1), 0)` and that for every `.Offset` you did in case you might place new columns in between existing ones.

Comment: @Notus_Panda, why a comment and not an answer? there are to many posts with answers in the comments and reflected as with no answer when filter questions. It is such a waste of time browsing questions already answered in thee comments.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this is what the OP was looking for, I for one didn't understand the need to step away from ´.Offset´. I understand the issue with giving an answer in the comments; will try to be more mindful about that.

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup: Non-Adjacent Return Columns By Title

**Source**

[image]

**Destination**

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LookupDataTitles()

    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Export"
    Const SRC_HEADER_ROW As Long = 1
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Prepare"
    Const DST_HEADER_ROW As Long = 5
    Const LOOKUP_TITLE As String = "ID"
    Const RETURN_TITLES As String = "Name,Last Name,Quarter,Group,Sales,Count"
    
    Dim ReturnCols() As String: ReturnCols = Split(RETURN_TITLES, ",")
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Adjust if it's not!!!
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim shrg As Range: Set shrg = sws.Rows(SRC_HEADER_ROW)
    Dim slCol As Long: slCol = Application.Match(LOOKUP_TITLE, shrg, 0)
    Dim slrg As Range
    With shrg.Cells(slCol).Offset(1)
        Set slrg = sws.Range(.Cells, sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Dim srCols(): srCols = Application.Match(ReturnCols, shrg, 0)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dhrg As Range: Set dhrg = dws.Rows(DST_HEADER_ROW)
    Dim dlCol As Long: dlCol = Application.Match(LOOKUP_TITLE, dhrg, 0)
    Dim dlrg As Range
    With dhrg.Cells(dlCol).Offset(1)
        Set dlrg = dws.Range(.Cells, dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Dim drCols(): drCols = Application.Match(ReturnCols, dhrg, 0)
    
    ' Get the matching row indexes.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(drCols)
    Dim srIndexes(): srIndexes = Application.Match(dlrg, slrg, 0)
    
    Dim srg As Range, drg As Range, sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Write the matches.
    For dr = 1 To UBound(srIndexes)
        If IsNumeric(srIndexes(dr, 1)) Then
            sr = srIndexes(dr, 1)
            Set srg = shrg.Offset(sr)
            Set drg = dhrg.Offset(dr)
            For c = 1 To cCount
                drg.Columns(drCols(c)).Value = srg.Columns(srCols(c)).Value
            Next c
        End If
    Next dr
    
    MsgBox "Data lookup finished.", vbInformation

End Sub
```